# XSLT 1.0 external-graphic

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I try to add qrcode JPG or PNG image to XSLT:
<fo:external-graphic src=“url(../qrcode.jpg)”/>

But, i returned SEVERE: NullPinterException

If I try add some image which is not qrcode, all work good. What is problem?

Comment: XSL-T can't tell if an image is a qrcode or not. Check name and path. Can you show the code for the other image that does work?

Comment: Hi, i changed question.

Comment: Indeed you have, but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: Also, check if qrcode.jpg has size 0 or is an invalid JPG file. You could also try opening it in an image processing program and then save it, and try again (or save it as a PNG, and try that one). Some JPGs are a bit too quirky for some FO processors.

Comment: Ok, i will try. Thanks.